# Unable to use "count" function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use simply use `count` on 1 variable using the data frame and $ to call the variable.  I am doing

```
count(customer_churn$Churn)
```

before installing `dplyr` I got following:

> Error in count(customer_churn$Churn) : could not find function "count"

After installing `dplyr` and calling the library I get:

> Error in UseMethod("summarise_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

I then tried using `summarise` instead and got the same error.

Comment: Could you provide some data?

Comment: Regarding the first error, you have to install the package before you can use its functions. For the second, [read the docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tally.html) to see how to call `count` and on what (a data frame, not a vector)

Comment: simple, need to import library "dplyr" as dplyr is a grammar of data manipulation, providing a consistent set of verbs that help you solve the most common data manipulation challenges.  count function is one of them.

Answer (score 6):

`count` expects a data.frame/tibble.  According to `?dplyr::count`.

> x - a tbl() to tally/count.

Second issue is the error when we don't load the package after installing.  It can be loaded by calling `library(dplyr)` or use explicitly `dplyr::count`

```
library(dplyr)
customer_churn %>%
      count(Churn)
```

---

In `base R`, the `table` can be applied to the `vector`

```
table(customer_churn$Churn)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(240)
customer_churn <- data.frame(Churn = sample(1:5, 50, replace =TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

So generally I will assume that your data has IDs and flag whether customer is churned or not, you can count using the following methods.

#### Dplyr method

```
library(dplyr)

customer_churn <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
    Churn = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
  )

customer_churn %>%
  count(Churn)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   Churn [2]
# Churn     n
# <dbl> <int>
#  0     7
#  1     3
```

#### Janitor method

```
janitor::tabyl(customer_churn, Churn)
```

#### Base R method

```
table(customer_churn$Churn)
```

Answer (score -2):

You may use `count` function from `plyr` (not `dplyr`) which behaves a bit differently and works fine with vectors.

```r
plyr::count(iris$Species)
#>            x freq
#> 1     setosa   50
#> 2 versicolor   50
#> 3  virginica   50
```

Comment: Why? They asked about a function in dplyr, not plyr, which is mostly retired anyway